# MFC dialog maximized is larger than monitor

Tags: c++, mfc, multiple-monitors

In WIndows 7, when I maximize an MFC dialog, using the system menu's small square button, the resulting dialog window is slightly larger than the physical dimensions of the screen. Why is this?

The `GetSystemMetrics` calls yield the correct monitor dimensions, and the screen resolution (right-click desktop) also shows the correct dimensions.

The WM_SIZE message, sent after the window is maximized, shows a size slightly larger than the monitor, consistent with the edge portions of the dialog being cut off. For example, on a 1920 x 1080 monitor, the maximized size from OnSize() is 1936 x 1096. Spy++ shows

> Rectangle: (-1928, -8) - (8, 1088), 1936 x 1096 (Maximized)
>
> Restored Rect: (-1188, 79) - (173, 849) 1015 x 770
>
> Client Rect: (8, 50) - (1928, 1088) 1920 x 1038

(the dialog was on the left monitor of a 2-monitor system).

I need to understand the exact definition of "maximizing a window", because I am rearranging some dialog windows on both single- and multiple-monitor systems in response to user changing window size and/or position.

Can someone please explain why I am seeing the results I describe, and how I can set up a dialog so the system menu's "maximize" button does not cause the dialog to expand past the physical boundaries of the monitor?

MFC, 64-bit Windows 7 Pro, Visual Studio 2013, C++

Comment: Do you have any 3rd-party multi-monitor software running?

Answer (score 2):

When you maximize a window, the non-client border area is moved to outside of the monitor. You can see that the client area is the same as the monitor size minus the size of the title bar.

P.S. There's no way to modify this behavior, Windows itself is in charge of the window dimensions when maximized. You might be able to modify the window to turn off the borders on `WM_SIZE` or something, but then you'd lose the caption bar.

Comment: This is correct, but not the whole story. On a 2-monitor system, you'd expect to see the 8-pixel border on an adjacent monitor, but it's not visible.

Comment: @Woody20 obviously those borders simply aren't painted. Just a guess, when the window is maximized a clipping region is set that covers the monitor and nothing else.

Comment: @Woody20 little did I know that the ultimate authority covered this subject just 2 weeks ago: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/03/04/10597470.aspx